# Getting error at print statement in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printing, 2d

Hello every one I have made a small function which takes a pointer to 2D array and fill it with word linearly i.e. I fill my 2D array row by row with the give word.I think its working fine but i got segmentation fault when I tries to print my array.Can any one help me where am I going wrong.

Thanks

```
void create_table(char *key ,char (*table)[5]){

    int row=0, col=0;
    while(*key){
        *(table + row++)[col++] = *key++; 
                printf("%c" , table[0][0]); // Here I got seg fault

        if(col == 4){
            col=0;
            row++;      
        }

    }       

}

//===================================

int main(){
    char table[5][5];
    create_table("monarchy" ,table);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is a good example for why it's not a good idea to write things like `*(table + row++)[col++] = *key++;`.

Comment: Anyway, this problem can be solved using a debugger, so vote to close.

Comment: Really sir i mean then how should i do it in a better way

Comment: By putting the increments on separate lines, so that it's clear what's happening.  Presumably you want something like `table[row][col] = *key; key++; col++;`.

Comment: ok sir thanks. I was thinking to do with minimum LOC

Comment: Minimizing lines of code is a pointless waste of time. Let the compiler do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 *(table + row++)[col++] = *key++;
```

Should not be "row++", just "row". You're incrementing "row" elsewhere already.

Comment: thanks alot sir... one thing more sir it my code not good means is it not a good way to do fill 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, a little more readable:

```
void create_table(char *key ,char (*table)[5])
{
    int len = strlen(key);

    int row=0, col=0;
    while (len--)
    {
        table[row][col] = *key;
        printf("%c\n" , table[row][col]); 
        col++;
        key++;

        if (col == 4)
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;      
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You too have the row++ in the wrong place. The one commented out is the correct one.